# Pie Chart Labels Cut off

Tags: r, plotly

I'm making a pie chart, and some of the labels get cut off. I'd like to shrink the plot to accommodate all the labels. Below is a reproducible example.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(type="pie",values=1:19,
        labels=c(101:119),textinfo="label+value+percent",
        textposition="outside",showlegend=F,marker=list(colors=c(
          "gray",
          "thistle",
          "red",
          "lightskyblue",
          "deeppink",
          "green",
          "gold",
          "brown",
          "purple",
          "orange",
          "cadetblue",
          "darkslategray",
          "burlywood",
          "yellow",
          "skyblue",
          "lightgreen",
          "hotpink",
          "lightgray",
          "blue"
        )))
```

Comment: not sure if this helps..certainly shrinks the plot. `domain=list(x=c(0.25,0.75), y=c(0.25,0.75))`

Comment: I was just playing around with that. It does shrink the plot, but because the labels are close together, plotly still places some of them very far from the pie. There might be other arguments that can be used to adjust this. For reference, all the arguments that can be added to plotly pie charts are [documented here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#pie).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this. Just set the margin, height and width in your layout() expression. Just play with the numbers until you get what you want. Hope it helps.

```
m = list(
  l = 40,
  r = 40,
  b = 50,
  t = 50,
  pad = 0
)

plot_ly(type="pie",values=1:19, height = 25,
        labels=c(101:119),textinfo="label+value+percent",
        textposition="outside",showlegend=F,marker=list(colors=c(
          "gray",
          "thistle",
          "red",
          "lightskyblue",
          "deeppink",
          "green",
          "gold",
          "brown",
          "purple",
          "orange",
          "cadetblue",
          "darkslategray",
          "burlywood",
          "yellow",
          "skyblue",
          "lightgreen",
          "hotpink",
          "lightgray",
          "blue"
        ))) %>%
  layout(autosize = F, width = 800, height = 800, margin = m)
```