# Subplot with Plotly in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I cannot get a side by side subplot of a piechart using the plotly library in R with R Markdown. Instead, it looks like the subplot is overlaying one pie on top of the other:

````
---
title: "Test Plotly Pie"
author: ""
date: ""
output:
   html_document:
      self_contained: no
---

```{r plotpie1, results='asis', tidy=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.retina=NULL, echo=FALSE, out.width = "99%", out.height="750p[![enter image description here][1]][1]x"}

require(plotly)
require(dplyr)

p1 <- plot_ly(type="pie",values=c(5,954), height = 7,
        labels=c("Change","No Change"),textinfo="label", hoverinfo="all",
        textposition="outside",showlegend=F,marker=list(colors=c(
          "lightskyblue",
           "deepblue"
        ))) %>%
  layout(autosize = T)

p2 <- plot_ly(type="pie",values=c(15,1325), height = 7,
        labels=c("Change","No Change"),textinfo="label", hoverinfo="all",
        textposition="outside",showlegend=F,marker=list(colors=c(
          "lightskyblue",
           "deepblue"
        ))) %>%
  layout(autosize = T)

p4 <- suppressWarnings(subplot(
   p1,
   p2,
   margin=0.05))

p4

```
````

I am using R 3.1.3 64-bit on a Windows 7 64-bit operating system. I am using the plotly package version: 2.0.16 (downloaded from Github in mid December of 2015).

Comment: the problem is with pie and subplots, not with Rmarkdown

Comment: As I suspected... Is the pie type not supported with subplot?  Or is there just a different way that you are supposed to call pie's within the subplot?

Comment: "Is the pie type not supported with subplot" it looks like it..maybe somebody else will come up with a solution, line and point graphs work fine. Pie chart don't really have x and y axis....

Comment: @MLavoie : So I took your answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002772/pie-chart-labels-cut-off) to modify my margins, and then I changed the out.width and height to smaller percentages, then threw a "float: left; position: relative" into the style tag, and that is the best answer I have thus far...  Works great though when I do that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am happy I was useful :-)  You should post your answer for future readers! People don't always look into the comments.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by **MLavoie**, I'll just add an answer in case someone finds it useful...

````
```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000), mode = "markers")
```

<div>
 <div style = "float:left">
 ```{r echo = F, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4}
 p
 ```
 </div>

 <div style = "float:right">
 ```{r, echo = F, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4}
 p
 ```
 </div>
</div>
````

Comment: I have the same problem. Neither the solution from MLovie or @royr2 works, though. Is that code for r? I don't understand the code