# plotly R API, is it possible to have subplots for pie charts?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm hoping to subplot two pie charts with plotly's R API. However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
library(plotly) 
ds <- data.frame(labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
             val1 = c(10, 40, 60),
             val2 = c(20,40, 50))

 p1 <- plot_ly(ds, labels = labels, values = val1, type = "pie") 
 p2 <- plot_ly(ds, labels = labels, values = val2, type = "pie") 

 subplot(p1, p2, margin=0.05)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214912/subplot-with-plotly-in-r

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it try @MLavoie

Comment: There's a nice example on their documentation page as well https://plot.ly/r/pie-charts/

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and answer. For pie charts using `plot_ly()` the regular *domain* parameter used inside `layout()` doesn't work. You'll need to specify the domains inside the `plot_ly()` and `add_trace()` calls like so:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(labels1 = LETTERS[1:5], values1 = sample(100:200, size = 5),
                 labels2 = LETTERS[6:10], values2 = sample(100:200, size = 5))

plot_ly(df, labels = labels1, values = values1, type = "pie", 
        domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4)), showlegend = F) %>% 

  add_trace(labels = labels2, values = values2, type = "pie", 
            domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1)), showlegend = F) %>% 

  layout(title = "Pie chart - subplot")
```

Hope this helps...